# Unable to cast object of type to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have been following the tutorial -> http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-2

I'm stuck in the topic - *Revising EntityDataSource Control Markup to Improve Performance*. When I set `ContextTypeName` property by removing `ConnectionString` and `DefaultContainerName`, i'm getting an error message;

`Unable to cast object of type 'ContosoUniversity.DAL.SchoolEntities' to type 'System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext'.`

Please note: Using the `ConnectionString` and `DefaultContainerName` works fine.

Comment: Are you using VS2012? If so, the first part of the tutorial contains a warning about that that you really need to pay attention to. The error you get is a likely result of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the link for MSDN Article below solved my problem when I was going through the same tutorial.

[MSDN Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/09/13/how-to-use-the-entitydatasource-control-with-entity-framework-code-first.aspx)!

Just change SchoolContext to SchoolEntities in the method SchoolContextEntityDataSource_ContextCreating()

The code there is like this:

```
protected void SchoolContextEntityDataSource_ContextCreating(object sender,    EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e)
{
   var db = new SchoolContext();
   e.Context = (db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
}
```

And add

```
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
```

Best regards,

Adit Malik

Comment: When you put in a link to an article please paste the relevant parts of it on stack as well. That way if you link ever breaks your post will still be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

First use from OnContextCreating method in EntityDataSource structral aspx code
and then implement OnContextCreating method:

```
    protected void StudentsEntityDataSource_ContextCreating(object sender, EntityDataSourceContextCreatingEventArgs e)
    {
        var db = new ContosoUniversity.DAL.schoolEntities();
        e.Context = (db as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;
    }
```

and add:
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;